# change font size in drop down list for wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, fonts, menu, size, dropdown

I have this drop down list which links to seperate pages on the site 
 http://www.daguerreiansociety.org/join-us/[page where drop down exists][1]

```html
<h4><span style="color: #660000;">Types of Membership:</span></h4>
<h4>Select Membership Type to Join:<select name="menu1">
<option value="http://www.daguerreiansociety.org/student">Select Membership Type</option>
<option value="http://www.daguerreiansociety.org/student">Student Membership</option>
<option value="http://www.daguerreiansociety.org/collector-dealer-membership">Collector / Dealer Membership</option>
<option value="http://www.daguerreiansociety.org/institutional-library-membership">Institutional / Library Membership</option>
<option value="http://www.daguerreiansociety.org/supporting-membership">Supporting Membership</option>
<option value="http://www.daguerreiansociety.org/preferred-membership/">Preferred Membership</option>
<option value="http://www.daguerreiansociety.org/premier-membership/">Premier Membership</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
 urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
 };
</script></h4>


  [1]: http://%20http://www.daguerreiansociety.org/join-us/
```

I would like to increase the font size as its very small on page   How can this be achieved??

Answer (score 0):

1. Get to your Wordpress dashboard.
2. Go down the left menu and click "Appearance"
3. When the new menu appears, click  "Edit CSS".

   - This should take you to a page with your main homepage and a sidebar with "Customizing Additional CSS" at the top and a blank white coding space taking up most of the page. There might be a popover when you get to this page, you can just close this.

     - Your webpage is active here, so navigate the page to see the font change that will be made below.

Looking at your site through the inspector, the menu is created using  tag.

- Note: You can access the inspector in Chrome by clicking (Cmd + Shift + i).

Based on this you can add specific styles to the select tag. Add the below to that blank coding box on the left. '??' is the font size you would like:

```
select {
    font-size: ??px;
}
```